# Splitting strings by both "\\" and "." with regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I have the following string:

```
  var str = 'd:\\projects\\my_project\\dist\\js\\example.js'
```

I want to split the string into an array as follows:

```
['d:', 'projects', 'my_project', 'dist', 'js', 'example', 'js']
```

How can do this with str.split(regex)? What is the proper regex I need?

Already tried `str.split('(\.|\\)')` and `str.split('\.|\\')` (i.e. w/out parenthesis)

Both `'\.'` and `'\\'` work when individually passed, but not combined.

Please help me regex masters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing string to to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) you need to pass `RegExp()`.

**Note:** If you will use brackets like `/(\.|\\)/)` the result will also include `.` and `\\`

```js
var str = 'd:\\projects\\my_project\\dist\\js\\example.js'
console.log(str.split(/\.|\\/))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a regular expression to `split`:

```js
var str = 'd:\\projects\\my_project\\dist\\js\\example.js';
const res = str.split(/\.|\\/);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

You were passing a string - it was looking for a literal pattern `.|\` which it couldn't find. A regular expression (regex) uses slashes `/`, not quotes `'` or `"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried to upvote, but not sure if you get credit because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @mepley if you can't upvote you can always mark the most appropriate answer as "answered" by clicking the tick

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you! Okay almost to 15 reputation now lol

Answer (score 2):

Other answers already explain that you need to pass a regular expression to [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead of a `string`. So, alternatively, you can use this regular expression: `/[\\.]/`. This regular expression defines a [Character Set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```js
var str = 'd:\\projects\\my_project\\dist\\js\\example.js';
console.log(str.split(/[\\.]/));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help! Tried to upvote you all.